# How to set confidence level for wilcoxsign_test (package coin)?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, wilcoxon-signed-rank

In R, the function `wilcox.test` takes the argument `conf.level = 0.095` (for example). Giving the same argument to the function `wilcoxsign_test` from the *coin* package returns a warning:

```
additional arguments conf.level will be ignored
```

**What default confidence level does `wilcoxsign_test` use, and how can I change it?**

*Or :* Why do I not need a confidence level for this function?

Comment: What are you trying to do - perform a test or estimate something with an associated confidence interval?

Comment: p is significant if it is smaller than the significance level. significance level must be chosen to fit the research topic. it is not a fixed value.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the confidence level of a confidence interval - in this case for the pseudomedian - with a p-value for a test. I'll post something later.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need (and in fact can't) set a confidence limit in `wilcoxsign_test` because the about of the function includes a p value. e.g.the first example in the help file for the function:

```
RoundingTimes <- data.frame(
  times = c(5.40, 5.50, 5.55,
            5.85, 5.70, 5.75,
            5.20, 5.60, 5.50,
            5.55, 5.50, 5.40,
            5.90, 5.85, 5.70,
            5.45, 5.55, 5.60,
            5.40, 5.40, 5.35,
            5.45, 5.50, 5.35,
            5.25, 5.15, 5.00,
            5.85, 5.80, 5.70,
            5.25, 5.20, 5.10,
            5.65, 5.55, 5.45,
            5.60, 5.35, 5.45,
            5.05, 5.00, 4.95,
            5.50, 5.50, 5.40,
            5.45, 5.55, 5.50,
            5.55, 5.55, 5.35,
            5.45, 5.50, 5.55,
            5.50, 5.45, 5.25,
            5.65, 5.60, 5.40,
            5.70, 5.65, 5.55,
            6.30, 6.30, 6.25),
  methods = factor(rep(c("Round Out", "Narrow Angle", "Wide Angle"), 22)),
  block = factor(rep(1:22, rep(3, 22))))

### classical global test
friedman_test(times ~ methods | block, data = RoundingTimes)
```

gives as output

```
Asymptotic Friedman Test

data:  times by
     methods (Narrow Angle, Round Out, Wide Angle) 
     stratified by block
chi-squared = 11.1429, df = 2, p-value =  0.003805
```

so, since p = 0.0038, you know it is significant at p = 0.05 (and, indeed, much below that).

Comment: you cannot interpret p without knowing the conf. level alpha

Comment: @what *You* choose your $\alpha$. The program doesn't need to know what you choose. I might choose a different significance level, but we both compare it to the same p-value.

Comment: why then does the function wilcox.test expect an argument conf.level and set a default for it?

Comment: @what: It doesn't expect it - it's optional - & it's for something other than the Wilcoxon signed-rank test itself: the computation of a confidence interval for the pseudomedian. It's explained in the help page.

Comment: I see. Nevertheless it's not optional. It has a default value, if you don't set it. So it "expects" it.

Comment: Doesn't do anything when `conf.int = FALSE` which is also the default. Try `?wilcox.test`.